# Docker-compose Error : cannot restrict inter-container communication

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I trying to run my application service by using `docker stack deploy` command. With this command I get following error:

```
"starting container failed: error creating external connectivity network: cannot restrict inter-container communication: please ensure that br_netfilter kernel module is loaded"
```

Docker-compose file for my service is as below, it contains only one service:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  app_service:
    image: app-image:latest
```

But if i try to run this service using simply `docker run app-image:latest`, then it runs correctly. What might be the issue here?

Following is the output of `docker info`:

```
Containers: 44
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 44
Images: 11
Server Version: 18.06.0-ce
Storage Driver: vfs
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: ifx6qbtt8ylkxqxgjbk67rc6e
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: p8s73udo6dq4ivm95frfrfb4f
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 1
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 10
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: 10.10.140.7
 Manager Addresses:
  10.10.140.7:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: d64c661f1d51c48782c9cec8fda7604785f93587
runc version: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-131-generic
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 8GiB
Name: RNI-PD-CT06
ID: UEG4:OVFJ:G55V:KIR4:QJD2:LQUJ:DVLQ:WKJY:AKQB:MKSO:Z4ZN:UF56
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 38
 Goroutines: 161
 System Time: 2018-08-20T12:25:06.808731767Z
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

Comment: try to reinstall docker

Comment: what is the versions (`docker info`) ?  And `docker inspect networks` ?

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko i have added `docker info` & `docker inspect networks` command outputs in my post

Comment: please use: docker network inspect

Comment: What is the out of the `lxc config show manager --expanded` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per WARNING message the `bridge-nf-call-iptables` is disabled, run code below to address that warning:

```
sudo sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
sudo sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=1
```

Also, make sure the `br_netfilter` module is enabled, to do that run command below and make sure `br_netfilter` is listed in the linux.kernel_modules:

```
 lxc profile show docker
```

If it's not listed, copy all values listed in the `linux.kernel_modules` and add `,br_netfilter` to the end of the copied value, than put all together in the command below instead of <[COPIED_LIST]>:

```
lxc profile set docker linux.kernel_modules <[COPIED_LIST]>
```

Comment: I am getting `sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables: No such file or directory` while running `sudo sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1`, does this mean there is some issue in my CentOS setup?

Comment: @rishi007bansod not necessary, what's about other commands ? Do you have remote nodes ?

Comment: We dont have any remote nodes. Currently there is only on node in swarm. `lxc` command is not present in my system, i will install it and let you know its output.

Comment: @rishi007bansod I guess it's important to enable bridge-nf-call-iptables

Comment: Also we are using linux containers in host VM. In this linux containers we have setup docker. How can I set parameter `sudo sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1` in linux container?

Comment: @rishi007bansod I guess that will help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/444090/modifying-sysctl-values-inside-lxc-container

Answer (score -1):

You need to add **network** for intercommunication between docker

```
You will need to add this tag -> network: dockerNetwork
```

and then

```
services:
  app_service:
    image: app-image:latest
  network: dockerNetwork

  app_service2:
    image: app-image2:latest
  network: dockerNetwork

network: dockerNetwork
```

Comment: After adding this network field, still getting same error